# How can i create a global NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, global-variables

Hei all

i try to learn how i can get a NSString global, i have this kind of files.

( my global class )

```
Globals.h 
Globals.m
```

( my first view )

```
FirstViewController.h
FirstViewController.m
```

( my secound view )

```
SecoundViewController.h
SecoundViewController.m
```

now i will make a kind of username in FirstViewController and when SecoundViewController loads its will make my input into NSLog() in first time.

hobe i can be help here, :)

Answer (score 3):

If you truly want a global string, you can simply define it outside of any class definition, function, etc. in your Global class.

In Global.h:

`extern NSString *globalString;`

In Global.m:

`NSString *globalString = @"a string";`

To reference it in another class:

```
#import Global.h
...
NSString *aString = globalString;
...
```

If you simply want to pass a string from your first view to your second, look into properties.

Comment: Can i changes my globalString between the views to?

Comment: You can change it wherever you want. I don't know your situation so I'm not sure if a global string is really what you should be using, but take a look at using a singleton as well.